# Simple UIStackView in UITableViewCell not working out height properly in IB

Tags: ios, uitableview, interface-builder, uistackview

My layout is the following:

```
Table View (dynamic prototypes, row: automatic height and estimate)
  Table View Cell (row height: default)
    Content View
      Stack View (axis: horizontal, alignment: center, distribution: fill)
        Image View (height: 70, width: 70)
        Label
```

The UITableView has all 4 constraints to its superview (top, bottom, leading and trailing). The same is for the UIStackView, relative to its superview.

The issue is that the row height is not computed inside interface builder and actually it points to the following conflicting constraints:

```
bottom = Stack View.bottom
height = 70
Stack View.top = top
centerY = Image View.centerY
```

I find this layout super simple and it puzzles my why it does not work.

Comment: Show the actual "conflicting constraints" message.

Comment: There are no apparent conflicts during runtime, but still, IB says there are...

Comment: What is the **centerY** constraint on the image view?

Comment: It is imposed by the Stack View, which aligns its views to the center, as stated by the alignment property.

Comment: Ah - sorry, I didn't notice your `(row height: default)` comment. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your current Storyboard looks like these first two images:

[image]

[image]

Then the issue lies with the fact that you have set a Height constraint on your image view of `70`, but the default height of a table view cell is only `44`. That doesn't leave enough room for auto-layout to satisfy all the constraints.

If you change the Row Height (in the Size Inspector pane) to `71`, the conflicting constraints go away:

[image]

Comment: That's indeed what was happening. I had hoped IB would be a little smarter and compute the row height based on the intrinsic size of its children. Also, it's weird that the row height should be 71 and not 70... and the fact that choosing an even taller row height (>71) is no issue for IB, given that all constraints are set to 'equal' and not 'greater than'.

Comment: The frame has a half-point "padding" (I believe to handle the separator line), so 71 is correct. IB doesn't "auto-adjust" the row height, because it has no way of knowing how you intend to use the cell -- different fixed height at runtime? auto-sizing height? etc